# IntelliJ title bar / top bar disappeared

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having an issue with IntelliJ Idea IDE :

The top (title) bar has become white and the information in it disappeared, it was quite useful because when you have multiple projects open in the same time, it displays the project name.

[image]

This the version i'm using :

> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.6 Build #IC-171.4694.73, built on March 2, 2018

Comment: What's the version of the IDE that you are using? What's written in Help | About?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a OS issue, rather than an IDE issue, restarting the application didn't do the trick but a few updates and after restarting the computer a couple of times, the top bar came back.

This is my OS version : `Microsoft Windows 10 Entreprise 10.0.17763 N/A version 17763`